# How to expand a table to add more information in an accordion style in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion

I've been having a lot of hiccups making this work. Essentially I want to be able to click on a row on my table to expand that row and provide additional information within there. I want it to be a toggled accordion style (drawers), so I can open multiple at once. The code is below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S</th>
            <th>R</th>
            <th>Se</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>Ser</th>
            <th>L</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in projects | filter:query | filter:quer | orderBy:orderProp">
            <td><b>{{x.a}}</b></td>
            <td>{{x.b}}</td>
            <td><u>{{x.c}}</u></td>
            <td>{{x.d}}</td>
            <td>{{x.e}}</td>
            <td>{{x.f}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

It forms a table with six columns which will loop through records and produce many sets of information. I want to be able to give these rows the ability to expand and collapse on click.

http://plnkr.co/edit/CO7ZHudbfR9TZxGTQfGZ

Thanks.

Comment: expand what and in what manner? demo has no extra data that isn't already being displayed

Comment: Like this essentially. http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/VGgbq/ However I want the ability to expand multiple at one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use **angular-ui-bootstrap** which provides a set of AngularJS directives based on Twitter Bootstrap's markup and CSS, and iterate through your data using `ng-repeat` on `<accordion>`.

```
  <accordion-group  ng-repeat="x in pro | orderBy:orderProp">
      <accordion-heading>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell"><b>{{x.a}}</b></div>
          <div class="cell">{{x.b}}</div>
          <div class="cell"><u>{{x.c}}</u></div>
          <div class="cell">{{x.d}}</div>
          <div class="cell">{{x.e}}</div>
          <div class="cell">{{x.f}}</div>
        </div>
      </accordion-heading>

   <div>
     Test Data
   </div>

  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Further, you may use css to display tabular data

```
.table{
  display: table;
  width:100%
}
.row{
  display: table-row;
}
.cell{
  display: table-cell; 
  width:20%
}
```

The advantage of using ui-bootstrap is, it provide access to native AngularJS directives without any dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript.

Here's the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nPd71vKeal3LWCxHLNs6?p=preview)

Comment: any idea how to add datatables in accordion's body

Answer (score 0):

It seems I figured it out. By using ng-click and a little bit of js you can do it quite easily. In the  you add this.

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="x in projects | filter:query | filter:quer | orderBy:orderProp">
            <td><a href="#" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"><b>{{x.a}}</b></a></td>
            <td>{{x.b}}</td>
            <td><u>{{x.c}}</u></td>
            <td>{{x.d}}</td>
            <td>{{x.e}}</td>
            <td>{{x.f}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr collapse="isCollapsed" ng-repeat-end="">
        <td colspan="3">
          <h3>Test</h3>
          <p>Test</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
        </tbody>
```

You need ui-bootstrap so add this to your scripts.

```
 <script data-require="angular-bootstrap@0.12.0" data-semver="0.12.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

And add this to your javascript, the addition being 'ui.bootstrap'

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",['ui.bootstrap']);
```

The a href is not necessary, it just highlights that you can click it. It is probably better to do this.

```
<td ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"><b>{{x.a}}</b></td>
```

That way clicking the cell will trigger the expand/collapse.